# Messenger bot can't publish

Tags: facebook-messenger-bot

I have created my own messenger bot. I need to publish it. I have submitted it to the verification process and they reviewed it. I can see the message "Approved". How can I make my bot live now. I can not see any option to make it live. Only testers can message with the bot. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the official dev docs around App modes. Also be aware of:

> Note that Business apps do not have app modes and instead rely on
> access levels, which provide the same functionality.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test/app-modes#live-mode

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/release

Comment: These links are very useful. thank you. But I have already read these links and I have done everything. What happens after approved the review.? Only testers and developers can chat with the bot. It does not work for the public

Comment: Submit a bug report https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/create